# Pydev first release date

Tags: pydev

it's a litle bit off-topic question but the answer would really help me.
Does anybody know the release date (year) of the first Pydev version? As far as I was able to find, I got year 2004. Is it correct? (I need it because of my Diploma Thesis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Friday, October 01, 2004 according to http://pydev.blogspot.com/